# How to repeat a loop until the end of my spreadsheet?

Tags: vba, excel

I need help on how to repeat this loop below until the end of my spreadsheet. I built 2 loops below to work on the first 50 rows and it works fine. However, I have another 7000 rows that I need to apply both of these loops to (the loops should work on 50 rows at a time).

The first loop assigns a value of 1 or 0 in coloumn O depending on the value in column K.

The second loop then adds 1 to each cell in coloumn O that doesn't contain 0 until the sum of the 50 cell array in column O equals 64.

```
Sub assign_values()

        For i = 2 To 51

            If Cells(i, "K").Value > 0 Then

               Cells(i, "O").Value = 1
               Else
               Cells(i, "O").Value = 0

          End If

      Next i

        For i = 2 To 51

            If Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("O:O")) = 64 Then Exit Sub
            Cells(i, "O").Value = Cells(i, "O").Value + 1

        Next i

    End Sub
```

Again, this loop works fine for the first 50 rows. However, I cannot seem to figure out how to get this loop to apply to the next 7000 rows.

You guys have been a great help to me and I appreciate all of your answers.

Thanks,

G

Comment: You can search for lastrow

Comment: why are you looping twice? Also just change the too xx value and you should be good OR try and dynamically refer to used ranges or find lastrow as Luuklag stated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub assign_values()

    Const BLOCK_SZ As Long = 50
    Dim rng, c, tot

    Set rng = Range("O2").Resize(BLOCK_SZ, 1) '<< first block of 50 rows

    'keep going while there's content in Col K (you may need to adjust
    '  where you check for content)
    Do While Application.CountA(rng.Offset(0, -4)) > 0

        For Each c In rng.Cells
            c.Value = IIf(c.Offset(0, -4).Value > 0, 1, 0) 'based on ColK
        Next c

        tot = Application.Sum(rng) '<< only need this once, then keep count
        For Each c In rng.Cells
            If tot < 64 Then
                c.Value = c.Value + 1
                tot = tot + 1
            Else
                Exit For
            End If
        Next c

        Set rng = rng.Offset(BLOCK_SZ, 0) '<< next block of cells
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Worked beautifully. Thanks Tim!